# feedburner url turns to question marks

Tags: rss, feedburner

Im using Apache's Url Rewrite engine to rewrite my blog post's urls in
hebrew.
Im using Feedburner as my rss provider.
everything works fine with my website, as well as with my rss.xml file.
the problem is when I click on a link from Feedburner: It turns all of
the hebrew characters into question marks. Here's an example:
the link:

`http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/Webdeskil/~3/v4V5nVxzOS8/כסף-באינטרנט-גוגל-אדסנס`

becomes:

`http://www.webdesk.co.il/articles/???-????????-????-??????`

So I figure out its a Feedburner issue, rather than an issue with my
code.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: feedburner doesnt encode a given url, so urls in hebrew have to be encoded before being "sent" to feedburner via `.rss`.

I used the built in PHP function `urlEncode()` and the problem was solved.